# How am I obtaining silicon with resistivity proportional to the number of conduction electrons?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, conductors

The resistivity of silicon is given by

$$\large\rho=\rho_0e^{\Large{{\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}}}$$

and the number of conduction electrons in a semiconductor conduction band is

$$\large n_{\text{conduction}}(T)\propto e^{\Large{\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}}$$

If we divide the resistivity by an exponential we get

$$\large\frac{\rho}{e^{\Large{\frac{E_g}{k_BT}}}}=\rho_0\frac{e^{\Large{\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}}}{e^{\Large{\frac{E_g}{k_BT}}}}=\rho_0e^{\Large{-\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}}$$

This means that we have

$$\large\rho\propto e^{\Large{-\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}}\propto n_{\text{conduction}}(T)$$ 
$$\large\rho\propto n_{\text{conduction}}(T).$$

Since the conductivity of a semiconductor increases with temperature, it follows that the number of conduction electrons increases with temperature. Thus we have

$$\large\rho\propto T.$$

Surely this wouldn't make sense, because it is suggesting that resistivity increases with temperature, yet we know that conductivity increases with temperature, and resistivity should be inversely proportional to conductivity...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your expression for the carrier concentration has the wrong sign in the exponent. It can't blow up if T goes to zero.

Comment: And your equations are simplifications, and so can't be taken to be true across all temperatures. Make it cold enough, and you won't have electrons in the conduction band, even for n-type silicon (beyond intrinsic levels, that is).